# Grab text from html <a> tag identified by class and input it into another textarea automaticaly

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, copy, paste

I have an html  tag generated by a WP plugin that includes a random link.
I need to pick up that generated link and write it in a textarea (from a contact form) but need it to be automatic.

Generated code containing the link (cannot be changed):

```
<p class="ozpital-wpwetransfer-success__url"><a 
href="we.tl/123">we.tl/123</a></p>
```

Code from textarea to auto write that link:

```
<p><textarea class="wpcf7-form-control"></textarea></p>
```

I've managed to create a workaround with a button but its not good, I need to automatize the code for no button, has we run the code it will auto write that link in the text area. Also i'm trying with paste event but doesn't have to be this way, I just don't have other idea!

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/xf_analog/cgfwup90

I think the demo its self-explanatory, all the help will be apreciated. Thanks

Comment: like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/eh6pruo4/

Comment: Or like this: https://jsfiddle.net/cgfwup90/39/. And the one without click https://jsfiddle.net/cgfwup90/43/. I made a simpler solution, I don't understand why did you overcomplicated with the copy/paste stuff in the first place.

Comment: Can you modify the JS for the we transfer? - If so you could dispatch an event - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

and listen for the event in your code, you could also pass the data with the event and omit the Link if its not needed.

Comment: Carsten, you nailled it :O but if I take out the button it stops working. Ionut last solution works great!

Comment: But probably have to use https://jsfiddle.net/cgfwup90/39/ because the other don't refresh the moment plugin generates the link, maybe I just have to have the button

Comment: I think the problem is that the plugin don't 'refresh' the page when the link is generated, so the function doesn't know there is a new string inside the href. It works with the button but without it the textarea remains empty even if the plugin generates the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that element gets generated dynamically, you can try doing something like this:

```js
window.onload = ()=>{
   let link;
   let linkValue = '';
   let textArea = document.querySelector('textarea.wpcf7-form-control');
  
  // generate the paragraph that has the link after 5 seconds
  setTimeout(()=>{
    // the containing paragraph
    let paragraph = document.createElement('p');
    // the anchor element that will be containing the link we want
    let anchor = document.createElement('a');
    let textNode = document.createTextNode('I am the target');
    anchor.appendChild(textNode);
    anchor.setAttribute('href', 'we.tl/123');
    paragraph.classList.add("ozpital-wpwetransfer-success__url");
    paragraph.appendChild(anchor)
    document.body.appendChild(paragraph);
  }, 5000);
  
  // check if the anchor element exists then grab the value of its
  // href attribute
  setInterval(()=>{
    // grab the anchor element inside the containing paragraph
    link = document.querySelector('p.ozpital-wpwetransfer-success__url a');
    // get the value of the element above
    if(link){
      linkValue = link.getAttribute('href');
    }
    // update the textarea's value if and only if the link is not in its own value
    if(linkValue !== '' && textArea.value.indexOf(linkValue) == -1){
      textArea.value = link.getAttribute('href')
    }
  }, 1000)
};
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p><textarea class="wpcf7-form-control"></textarea></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/ZqvpMN). :)

Comment: thats cool but I'm trying to integrate that in my code without results :( maybe I just don't have the skills :( not really a programmer

Comment: but I thing some like this code would be the solution to the refresh issue i mentioned above

Comment: @JohnnyF, all you'll need is the whole `setInterval` block. what happens is it periodically checks if the `<a>` element exists and if it does, the `href` attribute of that is retrieved and set as the value of the textarea :)

Comment: Ok, my bad... your code works. I was not applying the right way. This way its works smooth https://codepen.io/xf_analog/pen/WadROG

Comment: But if there is some text already in that textarea it stops working :) guess it needs tweaking :)

Comment: @JohnnyF, I've modified it so that the value of the textarea gets replaced with the value of the anchor's href attribute. See if that satisfies your requirement :)

Comment: Thank's!! Its better but this way the user is not able to add some text along with the link.

Comment: Its perfect. But I think I'm gonna separate the link field and the input text field. Its less confusing for the user, don't you think? The link appears in a textarea and then the user writes message in a different textarea :)

Comment: @JohnnyF, well, if user input is required, that would be better since you could also have the link's field set to read only :)

Comment: I'm trying to keep the textarea readonly but no success, can you give me a tip?

Comment: really thank's! I've got a lot to learn about coding. Its solved, thank's again!

Comment: just a small issue: its possible to have that behavior in more than one class? At this moment is related to 'wpcf7-form-control' but I would like it to happen in other forms with diferent class. thanks SOLVED! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple one,

HTML

```
<a href="google.com" class="aa">ff</a>
<textarea class="tt"></textarea>
```

JQuery

`$(document).ready(function() {
  let link = $(".aa").attr("href");
  $(".tt").val(link);
});`

Comment: thank's but without the 'refresh' that code will not get the link since its generated inside the plugin.